# Defining variable in XML file

Tags: android, xml

I have an XML file with 5 textviews, all with the same textSize. Currently, I define the size like this:

`android:textSize="30dp"`

However, I want a quick way to apply something like:

`android:textSize="text_size"`

Where textSize would be a variable I define somewhere, and can use wherever I want in my XML file. I tried defining these variables in the strings.xml file in the Android project, and calling them like this:

`android:textSize="@string/text_size"`

Where it would be defined like this in strings.xml

`<string name="text_size">30dp</string>`

It worked fine in Ecplise itself, and showed just fine in the Graphic Layout. But when I tried running the app on my phone, it crashed.

So, is there a way to define variables in my XML layout files? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea of putting it in `strings.xml` is close, but those values need to be set in a dimensions XML file. The documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Using your example, you might make a file called `res/values/my_dimens.xml`. Then put in there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_text_size">30dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then to use it in your layout, just set

```
android:textSize="@dimen/my_text_size"
```